# How to extend ZeroMQ with new socket types?

Tags: c++, zeromq

Is there a helper api for new socket types creation (for example to support chaining of operations to one particular receiver (alike transaction distributed in time, a dialog) and provide horisontal scaling for such long operation dialogs (count ammount of dialogs per node)?

So I want to create new socket type in ZeroMQ. Is there any support for such extensions/or at least examples besides default ZMQ sockets in ZeroMQ? Is there support for such things in clrzmq (one for .net)?

Comment: Fork the project, write your custom extension; I don't believe you can do it from the API. Then again, zmq supports RAW sockets, which means wire-level data has no frame constraints whatsoever, so you're free to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use ROUTER-DEALER sockets to design your semantics. If you can get an elegant model that you think would work at the lower level you can try to convince someone to add it, or you can try to add it yourself, in the code. If you know C++ it's not too hard; each socket type is a class.